# Combine flex and bison for file parsing

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I have this program in flex/bison.

My two problems are this :

1. I don't know how to make it work for file inputs because my university exercise need it work with files.

   I tried using iostream library from g++ compiler but i had many errors (I change of course `printf`s in `cout` etc)
2. I can't make it work as a float, I used `atof` declared `yytext` as boolean also still got nothing.

flex.l :

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%{
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "bison.tab.h"
    #define YYDEBUG 1
%}

%%
create_table {return CREATE;}
[ ][a-z]+ {return MONO;}
([ ][a-z]+[ ][&])+ {return CREATELIST;}

create_record_data {return RECORD;}
([ ][a-z]+)([ ]#[0-9]{1,2}) {return RECORDNUMBER;}

[0-9]+(["."][0-9]+)? {yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
"+" {return PLUS;}
"-" {return MINUS;}
"*" {return MULT;}
"/" {return DIV;}
"\n" {printf("Line : %d \n",yylineno);  return END;}
"\t" {return TAB;}
"(" {return PARL;}
")" {return PARR;}

%%
```

bison.y :

```
%{
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%token CREATE RECORD 
%token MONO CREATELIST RECORDNUMBER
%token NUMBER
%token PLUS MINUS MULT DIV PARL PARR
%token END TAB

%left PARL PARR
%left MULT DIV
%left PLUS MINUS

%start Input
%%

Input:
 | Input Line
;

Line:
 END
 | Expr END { printf("Result: %d \n", $1); }
 | Create_table END { printf("Create Table ! \n"); }
 | Create_record_data END { printf("Record Data Created ! \n"); }
;

Expr:
 NUMBER {$$ = $1;}
 | Expr PLUS Expr {$$=$1+$3;}
 | Expr MINUS Expr {$$=$1-$3;}
 | Expr MULT Expr {$$=$1*$3;}
 | Expr DIV Expr {$$=$1/$3;} 
 | PARL Expr PARR {$$=$2;}
 ; 

Create_table:
 CREATE MONO { printf("Create Table Single! \n"); } 
 | CREATE CREATELIST { printf("Create Table List ! \n"); }
 ;

Create_record_data:
 RECORD RECORDNUMBER Expr { printf("Record Created \n"); }
 ;

%%

int yyerror(char *s) {
  printf("%s \n", s);
}

int main() {
  if (yyparse()==0)
     fprintf(stderr, "Successful parsing.\n");
  else
     fprintf(stderr, "error found.\n");
}
```

Comment: Flex by default reads from the global `FILE *yyin` which is initialized to point at `stdin`.  You can set it to something else (eg a pointer returned from `fopen`) if you want to read from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main you can open a file or use stdin (this makes testing easier).

Say if you want to optionally accept an input filename as your first argument, change your main to look like:

```
extern FILE* yyin;
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
  yyin = NULL;
  if (argc==2) yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  if (!yyin) yyin = stdin;
  if (!yyparse()) {
    ...
```

For your other issue of "using" the tokens.

You can use the yytext to get the text that the scanner found that triggered the token, but you can't assign just assign this to a token. You have to use types.

If you want to get the value from the scanner (and not worry about yytext in the grammar, then above your %token section, add this:

```
%union
{
  int intval;
  float floatval;
}
...
%token <intval> NUMBER
```

Then, in your flex.l, you can assign to the union according to whatever type the token is:

```
[0-9]+(["."][0-9]+)? {yylval.intval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
```

Then, in your grammar, you can access the (int value in this case) using the $1 or $3 / etc. positional variable and get that atoi value.

Last thing, is you declare grammar for Expr but it has no type.

In the top section, below your tokens, you have to give non-terminals a type:

```
%type <intval> Expr // if an Expr is just a number
```

If you want to store more information in a Non-Terminal then you should probably make/use a struct, declare its type in the union, then you can set the type of the NT to your struct.

The only way to assign $$ (the left side of the production rule) is for $$ to have a type. With the above, giving Expr an int and the numbers ints ...

```
Expr : Expr PLUS Expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
```

should work

Comment: You can get EOF (end-of-file) when using stdin as your input with CTRL-D ; Win is CTRL-Z and Enter.

Comment: Thank you very much !! It worked like perfect ! i will post my problem for the first one because this specific worked for me ,thanks again :)

Comment: int main(int argc,char **argv) {

     yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");

     yyparse();

     fclose(yyin);

     return 0;

  

}            (Without yyparse() check)